# Creating an event via Siri in another time zone

Tags: ios, calendar, siri

I frequently need to create events in another time zone. For awhile, I would do this using Siri by saying “create event Call Mom at 4 PM Pacific Time.” The event would be created in the correct time zone. I could also set alarms using the same formulation.

After some update a few years ago, Siri lost the ability to understand this formulation. Have they actually removed this ability entirely, or is there just a new formulation I haven’t discovered yet? It’s hard to believe that you can no longer do this very common thing.

Open to workarounds involving Shortcuts as well, if that’s what’s needed.